# Getting error in android app - The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Organization.YourDownload, int, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Tags: android, android-context

Displaying List of Organizations in a list view.Using async task  via url iam fetching the Organization names in the list view.The details of each organization are displayed on a new activity when any of the organization name is clicked.
However iam getting this error The constructor ArrayAdapter(Organization.YourDownload, int, int, ArrayList) is undefined
.Thanks in advance

```
public class Organization extends ListActivity {

    XMLGettersSetters data;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
    private Context mActivityAContext;
    private static Organization _appCtrl;



    // private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    // private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private final int MENU_ORG = Menu.FIRST;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           Organization._appCtrl = this;




         // this.setTitle(R.drawable.add_org);
           getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.drawable.add_org);
          // setTitle(R.drawable.add_org);

          new YourDownload().execute();


       }

       class YourDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           try{
                  SAXParserFactory saxPF= SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                       SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
                       XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();

                       URL url = new URL("http://xyz/get_organization_details");

                       XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
                       xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                       xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                  }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }

               return null;

           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

               super.onPostExecute(result);
               data= XMLHandler.data;

               ListView lv = getListView();
               lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

               LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
               ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_addorg, lv, false);
               lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

            //Organization.getAppCtrl();

               this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label,data.getName()));

               lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                 // selected item 
                 String name = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                for(int i=0;i<data.getId().size();i++){

                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(data.getName().get(i).toString()))
            {


                 String email = data.getEmail().get(i).toString();
                 String address=data.getAddress().get(i).toString();
                 String url=data.getUrl().get(i).toString();
                 String postcode = data.getPostcode().get(i).toString();
                 String id_org = data.getId().get(i).toString();
                 Log.v("ID",id_org.toString());
               //  Log.v("postcode",postcode.toString());


                 // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleListItem.class);
                 // sending data to new activity
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                intent.putExtra("address", address);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("postcode", postcode);
                intent.putExtra("id_org", id_org);

                 startActivity(intent);
            }
                }


                 }

               });


           }

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               // pre execute logic
               super.onPreExecute();
           }

       }




       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 11, 0, "Add Organization");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == 11) {
    //setCategoryReportValues();
    addorgm();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static Organization getAppCtrl()
    {
        return _appCtrl;
    }
    public void setContextForActivityA(Context context) 
    {
        mActivityAContext = context;
    }
    public Context getContextForActivityA()
    {
        return mActivityAContext;
    }
    private void addorgm() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Organization.this,AddOrg.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

**this** is point to your YourDownload instance not to the Organization.

When you used this in inner class it will consider this instance of the inner class not the super class when you want to use the Main class or say super class.

You can use this by giving the class name of Parent class in your case

```
Organization.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Organization.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label,data.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `ArrayAdapter` expects an instance of `View` as the first argument. You're initializing it inside your nested subclass `YourDownload`. Try this instead:

```
Organization.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Organization.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label,data.getName()));
```

Comment: Tried doing that too.But still getting the same error-The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type Organization.YourDownload

Comment: Fix the first "this" to point to Organization too (response edited)

Comment: Thanks for your response..its running.But whenever the Organization activity starts,a black screen is displayed for few seconds and then the listview is shown

Comment: If this helped you, you should accept the answer and create a new question for your new problem (since it's a different topic). In that question, include any relevant logs and information you can glean through using the debugger.